# How can I display only the buildings of the selected customers on my ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

so, I need to make a form, and I need to display information inside the database for specific customers, say we have John doe, who is a customer and has a building at 23 nowhere blvd, so If I select John doe, I will only get John's building back. I am using ruby on rails, running ruby 2.6.5 and rails 5.4.2 I've been reading about form helpers for an hour now but not too sure how I will do this here's what I have right now to select my customers using Bootstrap-forms gem

```
<%= bootstrap_form_with(model: @intervention, local: true) do |customer_selection| %>
   <%= customer_selection.collection_select :customers, Customer.all, :id, :company_name %>
   <%= customer_selection.submit "Start Intervention" %>
 <% end %>
```